# How to wait for all threads to complete before executing next line

Tags: ruby

I have something like below:

```
all_hosts.each do |hostname|   
  Thread.new {
    ...
  }
end
# next line of execution
```

Each of the hosts above opens its own thread and executes the commands. I want to wait for all threads to finish executing before moving onto next part of file. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Thread#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-join) which will wait termination of the thread.

To do that you need to save threads; so use `map` instead of `each`:

```
threads = all_hosts.map do |hostname|   
  Thread.new {
    # commands
  }
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Thread` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Thread.html) explains it:

> Alternatively, you can use an array for handling multiple threads at once, like in the following example:
>
> ```
> threads = []
> threads << Thread.new { puts "Whats the big deal" }
> threads << Thread.new { 3.times { puts "Threads are fun!" } }
> ```
>
> After creating a few threads we wait for them all to finish consecutively.
>
> ```
> threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
> ```

Applied to your code:

```
threads = []

all_hosts.each do |hostname|
  threads << Thread.new { ... }
end

threads.each(&:join)

# next line of execution
```